# Can't use any kind of "super" key combinations for keybindings in Ubuntu 12.04 from the control center

Tags: 12.04, shortcuts

I've changed my Unity launcher from <kbd>super</kbd> to <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> because I (used to) set a lot of commands with <kbd>super</kbd> keybindings. It appears to not work at all in Ubuntu 12.04.

Is there a solution ?

Thanks !

OT: also, <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>q</kbd> fails since <kbd>ctrl+q</kbd> closes the gnome control center...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replacing "super" with "Mod4" in *~/.gconf/desktop/gnome/keybindings/custom0/%gconf.xml* seems to work for me. There might be compatibility issues if you bind already existing shortcuts, say "Mod4+Tab".

"Alt+.." doesnt work either (after restarting X) for me. I have no solution for that. Why they dont put all shortcuts in the same place is beyond me... One place where every app could read/write the same shortcuts.. but that's another issue.

Comment: Thanks, looks like it works ! It's not ... straight forward, to say the least, but it works. It's now labeled as 'super+hyper' in the gnome-control-center..

Answer (score 1):

Install CompizConfig Settings Manager (CCSM)

```
sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
```

Open CCSM from System Tools>Preferences>CompizConfig Settings Manager

Open "Commands" under the General group. Enable by check marking the box on the left.

Log off, log on. (Restart X)

Comment: Shoud that alone make the gnome control center "super" bindings work ? Or are you suggesting to set keybindings in Compiz-Commands instead ?
Because I already have "Commands" enabled and Im using it for "edge" bindings. Im afraid the limit of 20 commands isn't enough for me.

Comment: +1 for this finally helping to "fix" ubuntu 12.04. Unity's behavior with the super key is annoying at best, bizarre otherwise. I use Autokey-QT and "launchers" to do all sorts of useful things with the Super key, which Unity has undone. :P