# How to make a shortcut under ubuntu?

Tags: shortcut-keys, quickly

I use ubuntu 12.04 with unity, I want to map may own hot key in order to quick launcher, for example, I can  run ctrl+alt+t to run terminal, can I run ctrl+e to launch emacs?

Answer (score 1):

Under `All Settings -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts` you can define them.

When you add a new shortcut, in the upper input box write the name for it (ex. `This is an editor`), in the input box below enter the command to start the desired program (ex. `gedit`), then press `Apply` (I think,  I am not on English locale, sorry...). After that SELECT the newly added row from the list. You will see that `Disabled` is changing to  `New shortcut...` Press your desired combination, and you will see it in your list afterwards.

Comment: Yes, I have define my shortcut, but it appeared disable, How can I enable it?

Answer (score 0):

Install `Autokey-Qt`, it is an amazing automation tool. It can launch programs, send keystrokes, execute scripts. Quite amazing, really.

Edit: Seems that Autokey prefers not to be a program launcher. As I am quite the `Super+` program launcher fiend, I also ran into lots of problems adapting to 12.04 and Unity. Ultimately, [this post's answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/127330/cant-use-any-kind-of-super-key-combinations-for-keybindings-in-ubuntu-12-04-f) got it working for me. One of the big problems is having to avoid Unity's [built in mappings](http://freshtutorial.com/ubuntu-12-04-keyboard-shortcut-complete-guide/?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed:%20Freshtutorialdotcom%20%28freshtutorialdotcom%29). It would seem they always "fire" regardless of any other setting.

Sadly, the built in System Settings-> Keyboard -> Shortcuts tool does little. I wasn't able to add any working launchers here and instead used CCSM:

```
sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
```